# Make the Sublime SFTP Package quick panel display for longer

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I have configured sublime text 3 with [SFTP package](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) for my website (which works great).

There is a small annoying issue though:

- I select an operation like `Sync Remote -> Local`
- Once the sync has finished the quickpanel displays **only** for 1-2seconds and then disappears.
- If I miss the quickpanel, I have to start the process again (which could be minutes).

How do I make the quickpanel that appears (usually with 2 options  `Yes` or `No`) stay for longer. So I can set it to sync, get on with something else and then come back to it.

I really don't think I should be anxiously waiting for the panel to pop up, only for me to notice too late and having to start the whole process again!

Here is one of my (many) frustrating fails: 
[image]

Comment: Googled the problem and ended up here.  It seems that the panel will stay up for as long as you need as long as you aren't clicking anywhere else.  It is incredibly annoying as you can't really do anything else until you've clicked yes/no.

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked a long time ago, but while trying to bring up the SFTP upload panel and failed, I stumbled upon this thread. With *Package Manager*, I did `Ctrl+Alt+P` and typed `sftp:show` in the input box and got the **SFTP:Show Panel** command.

We see the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+U, Ctrl+Alt+S`, but pressing it, I didn't get anything, maybe a conflict with other shortcuts. So by simply clicking on the **SFTP: Show Panel** command, the panel opens.

For the panel to stay longer, you must set the option `hide_output_panel`. Open the user option for SFTP, `SFTP.sublime-settings`, Preferences -> Package Settings -> SFTP -> Settings User and enter :

```
{
   // Hide the output panel:
   //  - false  = never
   //  - number = seconds after completion
   //  - true   = always
   "hide_output_panel": 4,
}
```

I left the comments found in the default SFTP settings.
If we set the option to `false`, the panel will only close by pressing `Esc`.

Comment: This answer changed my life - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP has some options for that to put on your sftp-config.json file at the root of your folder :

Set those values to false like this:

```
"confirm_downloads":false,
"confirm_sync":false
```

I would leave

```
"confirm_overwrite_newer":true
```

to make sure to not lose data.

[SFTP documentation](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings#setting-confirm_sync)